# std::thread issue using wsocket32

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, winsock2

Sorry for the poor title im not sure what to title it because im not sure what the issue is.

I'm working on a project for grad school and I am using a library provided by the professor but its not working and haven't been able to get a reply from him.

The library provided is called `Sockets`. Within this project there is a `SocketListener` class. this class contains a `start()` method. within this method it is using std::thread to call a passed in `CallableObj` (Functor, lambda, or function ptr).

The includes are :`<windows.h>` `<winsock2.h>` `<WS2tcpip.h>` `<IPHlpApi.h>`. As is I am getting a few errors (any code dealing with std::thread objs):

```
- C2039 'thread': is not a member of 'std'
- C2065 'ListenThread': undeclared identifier
- C2228 left of '.detach' must have class/struct/union
```

Basically it doesnt know what std::thread is but this is my professors code and it should work as provided

I noticed `#include <thread>` wasn't included so I added it and now i get different errors in a file called xthread.h which isn't one of my files so i don't think i should be getting errors here.

```
- C2893 Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...) noexcept(<expr>)'
- C2672 'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found
```

I will make any changes and provide any needed data to this post, just be respectful and ask.

Comment: [mcve] please. It seems there are missing includes `<thread>` and other or missing compiler option `-std=c++14` or 11.

Comment: xthread.h is a file internal to the visual c++ standard library, you may get errors here but they will almost certainly be due to code you provide rather than in the library itself. Look up the error message and examine the first piece of code that is _not_ part of the standard library (either your code or the professor's - it may well be that the error is in the prof's code but it could just as easily be due to a parameter you provide).

Comment: @SoronelHaetir I am passing in a lambda to the function Start(): `auto myLambda = [&](){//some code here}; socketListener.Start(myLambda)` professor code (co is the callable object passed in by me): `std::thread ListenThread([&](){std::thread clientThread(std::ref(co), std::move(clientSocket));}`